# Оптимизация mysql запросов

Tags: php, оптимизация, mysql

Назрело несколько вопросов по оптимизации mysql запросов.

К примеру, на главной странице форума выводятся последние 5 сообщений. Формат такой: форумная тема - короткий текст - ник - группа пользователя. До недавнего момента я бы писал что-то типа такого:

```
/*
таблица posts: id, user_id, theme_id, text
таблица users: id, nick, group_id
таблица themes: id, name
таблица groups: id, name
*/
$posts = $db->execAndReturnAll('select `id`, `user_id`, `theme_id`, `text` from `posts` order by `id` desc limit 5');

$users = array();
$themes = array();
$groups = array();

$l = sizeof($posts);
for($i = 0; $i < $l; ++$i)
{
if(!in_array($posts[$i]['user_id']), $users)
    $users[] = $posts[$i]['user_id'];
if(!in_array($posts[$i]['theme_id']), $themes)
    $themes[] = $posts[$i]['theme_id'];
}

$users = $db->execAndReturnAll('select `id`, `nick`, `group_id` from `users` where `id` in (0,'.implode(',', $users).')');
$themes = $db->execAndReturnAll('select `id`, `name` from `themes` where `id` in (0,'.implode(',', $themes).')');

$l = sizeof($users);
for($i = 0; $i < $l; ++$i)
{
if(!in_array($users[$i]['group_id']), $groups)
    $groups[] = $users[$i]['group_id'];
}

$groups = $db->execAndReturnAll('select `id`, `name` from `groups` where `id` in (0,'.implode(',', $groups).')');
```

Но меня что-то берут сомнения, а целесообразно ли посылать 4 простых запроса к БД или расходы на передачу запросов туда-обратно себя не окупят и лучше написать один сложный запрос?

2) Стоит ли перекладывать на mysql всевозможные расчеты или лучше оставить это php? То есть, что лучше:

```
$data = $db->execAndReturn('select `width`, `height`, `width`*`height` as `square` from `rectangles` limit 1');
```

или

```
$data = $db->execAndReturn('select `width`, `height`, from `rectangles` limit 1');
$data['square'] = $data['width'] * $data['height'];
```

3) Есть ли какие-либо инструменты для тестирования скорости запросов к БД?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Вашем случае лучше написать один сложный.

По поводу расчетов, mysql сделает их быстрее.

Все таки php - это интерпритатор и любые лишние действия - это нагрузка.

Но судя по Вашему коду, у Вас не нагруженный проект, так что такие действия (такие, как умножение) делайте там, где Вам удобнее :)

Инструменты для тестирования:

```
explain...
```

и

```
$start_time = microtime(true);

// выполнение действий

$exec_time = microtime(true) - $start_time;
```

Comment: Благодарю, самому понадобится скоро.

Comment: Спасибо. А бывают ситуации, когда лучше разбивать запрос? И чем интерпретатор mysql лучше интерпретатора php?

Comment: Я стараюсь не разбивать запросы, лучше писать в один запрос. Бывают ситуации, когда у вас модульная система. Если нужны несколько запросов, то лучше их сделать процедурой прямо в мускуле. А лучше тем, что он на сях :)

Comment: Так пхп тоже на сях).

Comment: Я и говорю, что быстрее будет обрабатываться десятки строк некэшируемого скрипта php или один запрос на обработку в БД mysql?

Comment: Резонно. Спасибо).

Comment: @ling, 
"Спасибо. А бывают ситуации, когда лучше разбивать запрос?" - да, представьте что у вас база на 200К записей. Вы присоединяете LEFT JOIN'ом к ней колонку с именем пользователя из таблицы пользователей, и результирующий массив в php вырастает на 200 000 ячеек, хотя юзеров у вас 100. mysql как бы все равно, она отдаст, а вот php может погибнуть. Я допустим просто извлек юзеров в массив и потом при выводе уже на php подставлял имена вместо id. Естественно, это специфический случай и на последнюю инстанцию истины я не претендую.

Answer (score 1):

1) Зависит от того, сколько данных возвращается в ответах на эти запросы и где находится сервер БД (на той же машине или где-то в сети), тогда, возможно, стоит ориентироваться на скорость передачи данных и загрузку канала.

UPD->Regarding Alex Silaev

Например в данном случае (привожу только маленький пример):

```
'select `id`, `nick`, `group_id` from `users` where `id` in (0,'.implode(',', $users).')'
```

Лучше поправить в один запрос, который выполнится на стороне MySQL:

```
'select `id`, `nick`, `group_id` from `users` where `id` in (select `user_id`from `posts` order by `id` desc limit 5)'
```

Как-то так, просто для примера.

2)По моему мнению, стоит. На сегодняшний день существует множество агрегатных функций, которые с БД работают очень быстро и выводят данные с ошеломительной скоростью. Любая статистика выводится безумно быстро.

3) Была парочка инструментов, но уже не помню по склерозу. Вообще часто сталкивался с оптимизацией запросов, которые заносятся в журнал медленных запросов. Можно проанализировать переменные MySQL и статистику, выделив как быстро она (БД) работает, как эффективно используется память и т.п. Но это уже больше дело системного администратора.

Answer (score 1):

ну вообще по поводу выбора, то второй чуть лучше вариант!
А вообще попробуйте поюзать вьюхи)

Comment: Вьюхи?

Comment: VIEW, 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

Но я бы не советовал, если будете распространять свое творение, так как есть права на создание вью, либо использовал с проверкой прав.

Comment: Интересная идея, спасибо).

Answer (score 1):

phpmyadmin показывает время выполнения запроса, мне кажется очень удобным тестировать запросы в нем

Answer (score 1):

чем меньше запросов к mysql тем лучше. один сложный запрос всегда лучше, чем несколько простых. особенно нежелательно делать запросы в циклах.
а вот где посчитать width*height большой разницы нет. 
можно с тем же успехом после выборки из базы, сделать цикл и в нем произвести вычисления.
конечно, с обычным умножением и mysql справится легко, но бывают и более сложные операции, которые проще вынести на php.

пример:

```
    $list = array();
$sqlRes = mysql_query("select height,width from ... ");
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($sqlRes))
{
    $res['square'] = $res['height']*$res['width'];
    $list[] = $res;
}
```